# What is a best practise for multidimensional parameters map?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

Good day Stackoverflow community!

I would like to know any best practices for the following problem:

I need to build a system that will return certain value (say, partner ID) based in several input parameters, example in pseudo-code:

```
if GENDER == FEMALE and COUNTRY == GERMANY and AGE BETWEEN 21 and 30
    then return PartnerA
if GENDER == FEMALE and COUNTRY == GERMANY and AGE BETWEEN 31 and 40
    then return PartnerB
if GENDER == MALE and COUNTRY == GERMANY
    then return PartnerC
if GENDER == MALE and COUNTRY == FRANCE
    then return PartnerA
```

As you can see there's a possibility that for some parameter there'll be no special value, in this case the system should fall back to the closest available variant OR at least to the default value. Also the list of the parameters can grow over time (i.e. someone can add another dimension at any time).

My best ideas is to use multidimensional array and traverse the parameters one by one:

```
$map[COUNTRY][GENDER][AGE_RANGE] = VALUE;
if (isset($map[$country][$gender][$age_range])) {
    return $map[$country][$gender][$age_range];
} else {
    // traverse over each level of the $map array, testing each of them as "input parameter" -> "DEFAULT parameter value"
    // In the worst scenario I will end with $map[DEFAULT][DEFAULT][DEFAULT] value.
}
```

But I don't like this algorithm  as it seems to be too ineffective :/ Also, there'll be certain problems  when new parameter will be introduced (Where should a new dimension be inserted? How should we rebuild the array?).

Do anyone have a better ideas how to implement such a system?